# Button push to specific tab bar item?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I thought this is quite simple but I can't seem to find the answer. I have a view controller with 3 buttons, one of these buttons has a push segue to a tab bar controller. When pressed I presume it loads the '0th' tab item which is the fine for the first button but how do I then get the other two buttons to push segue to the other two tabs?

I have read a lot of articles but none of them seem to have the answer that I'm looking for. I already have the tab bar controller and all the sub-views created in the storyboard, I just can't seem to get an instance of the UITabBarController.

I have 2 logical ways of doing it in my mind but I am quite new to objective-c and can't work either of them out for the life of me.

The first is to programmatically load the uitabcontroller and set which item I'd like to load but I can't seem to find a way of invoking an already existing tab bar controller. Something like this (I know it loads a random view which is not what I exactly want):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1ViewController];
```

My other idea was to either override / hijack the segue or the load event of the tab bar controller and find out who called the segue and then if they are one of my other buttons and then switch to the relevant tab item using:

```
[myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]
```

I just can't seem to put it all together. I suspect the latter idea requires app delegates which I don't quite understand yet.

I apologise for this in advance - I realise that I'm in completely way over my head! (btw... I have moderate PHP and C# OOP experience so I understand 'some' things.)